# Change sensitivity for jquery tinyscrollbar on mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, tinyscrollbar

I'm using the [jQuery tinyscrollbar](http://baijs.com/tinyscrollbar/) plugin.

Is there anyway to change the sensitivity of the scrolling on mobile? It's super sensitive for long pages.

Have tried setting `wheelSpeed` to `160` but it doesn't seem to have any effect to the scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote the _drag function and it worked for me. But in my case, I'm not using a track thumb, only the scroll event.

```
function _drag(event) {
    if (self.hasContentToSroll) {
        var mousePositionNew = isHorizontal ? event.pageX : event.pageY,
            thumbPositionDelta = hasTouchEvents ? (mousePosition - mousePositionNew) : (mousePositionNew - mousePosition),
            thumbPositionNew = Math.min((self.trackSize - self.thumbSize), Math.max(0, self.thumbPosition + thumbPositionDelta));

        if (thumbPositionDelta < 0) {
            self.contentPosition -= self.options.wheelSpeed;
        } else {
            self.contentPosition += self.options.wheelSpeed;
        }
        self.contentPosition = Math.min((self.contentSize - self.viewportSize), Math.max(0, self.contentPosition));
        self.thumbPosition = self.contentPosition / self.trackRatio;

        $container.trigger("move");

        $thumb.css(posiLabel, thumbPositionNew);
        $overview.css(posiLabel, -self.contentPosition);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly with the `wheelSpeed` option now.

Comment: *edit*: well, kinda buggy when I tried to scroll up and down quickly.